# List iPhone application document files

Tags: iphone, list, file, document

Is there a way to get the filenames of the files in an iPhone application's document-folder? How do you do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory];
    for (NSString *s in fileList){
        NSLog(s);
    }
```

Comment: Note: directoryContentsAtPath is deprecated, use contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: instead