# Xcode - Can't see files in Documents directory using File Sharing

Tags: xcode, itunes, file-sharing

can somebody please help! I'm creating audio files using Xcode and placing those files in the 'documents' directory of my app, the point being that I can retreive them using iTunes and File Sharing.

I save the audio files as type .caf, I've created a directory list to make sure that all my files are actually there, they are. I NSLog the directory that the files are being stored to, it's the application documents folder. I have 'UIFileSharingEnabled/Application Supports iTunes Sharing' as TRUE in the info.plist. Everything seems to be working fine, EXCEPT... I just can't see the files in iTunes File Sharing. I KNOW they're there... I can even email them successfully from the same directory, but they don't show in iTunes.

Please can somebody help!
Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: ...if it helps iTunes File Sharing doesn't even show the .sqlite file, which is also in the documents folder. It just shows nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying doesn't really makes sense.
If you've done all the things you've mentioned properly, you should have had access to the application directory through iTunes.

Nevertheless, considering some problem still happens, you can do the following:

If you have SSH access to your phone (for jailbreak iPhone), you can use SSH to list the files on the documents directory.

If you don't have SSH, you have to solve the problem internally - through your application.
I recommend: [List iPhone application document files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433514/list-iphone-application-document-files)